# Failed to configure Postgres in PhpStorm

Tags: postgresql, phpstorm

I am trying to configure PostgreSQL in PhpStorm. It was working before till I removed my vagrant box and re install it again.

Every time I try to configure Postgres I get the following message:

> The specified user/password combination is rejected: [28000] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.0.2.2", user "dev", database "dev", SSL off

I am sure that user name is correct as well as database name.

[image]

Comment: It's not the username/password, it's the access configuration. Your computer is not allowed to connect to the server. Search this site for "*no pg_hba.conf entry for*" there are many questions regarding this

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name sorry which site?

Comment: Well _this_ site: stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]++no+pg_hba.conf+entry